# How do you set the return value of a mocked function?

Tags: go, gomock

I am using [gomock](https://code.google.com/p/gomock/) to create mock objects for unit testing. The following gives the mock object a method called GetQuestionById and tells the mock controller to expect the method to be called with argument 1:

```go
gw.EXPECT().GetQuestionById(1)
```

But how do I specify that the mocked method should return a particular value?

Answer (score 7):

When you call `gw.EXPECT().GetQuestionById(1)`, it ends up calling the method `RecordCall` on the mock controller. `RecordCall` returns a `Call`, and `Call` has a method called `Return` that does exactly what you want:

```go
gw.EXPECT().GetQuestionById(1).Return(Question{1, "Foo"})
```